Manhwa where the (female) main character can see how and when someone will die
So the story begins when the main character was little and had an accident that made her lose her memory. Afterwards, she realized that she could see how people would die and what causes them to die.
She did not try to stop it, until one day she saw that there were people who were still alive even though he had been predicted them to die tomorrow. She concluded that what she saw was just an estimate and called this ability, if I'm not mistaken, the possibility of someone dying.
She lives in a small village and this manhwa has a medieval setting. I don't recall if there's any magic in the story.

Thankyou. This is really what I've searching.

You're very welcome

This is I Can See Your Death by Dan Hae-neul.

Essie Ash can see how and when people will die. One day, she finds an
injured man in her backyard and discovers that he is Prince Pell. To
her shock, she notices that her parents' and other residents' death
dates have moved up since Pell's arrival. Essie asks him to leave,
hoping things will change, but changes her mind when Pell saves her
from his brother's assassins. She soon decides to join him on his
journey to the capital, but can't help but wonder why she's the cause
of his future death...


